# Remmina can't connect by hostname, must use IP

Tags: remmina

I have a Remmina connection, setup like so: (either `js-cc-10`, or `js-cc-10.local`)
[image]

When I try and connect, I get:

```
Couldn't convert 'js-cc-10' to host address
```

But, I can do:

```
dig js-cc-10.local
```

Which gives me the IP `192.168.x.x`, and I CAN connect using Remmina by the IP address.

Can I make Remmina work via `hostname`, rather than IP address?

Comment: Did you actually try with `js-cc-10.local` rather than just `js-cc-10`? The `.local` suffix is significant (implies avahi/zeroconf lookup)

Comment: Does the command `host hostname` resolve correctly? Also, what is the output of the line starting with `hosts:` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried with and without the .local suffix. `host js-cc-10` says not found, `host js-cc-10.local` returns the correct IP address. The hosts line is `hosts:          files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]`

Comment: Can you ping the hostname, and does it show the correct IP when you do so?

Comment: Yep, shows everything correctly.

Comment: Same. It seems it doesn't resolve .local addresses. I can ping the address but host doesn't work. The host command uses DNS and .local are mDNS / Avahi / Bonjour but Remmina doesn't seem to resolve them.

Comment: FWIW, I had this working on Lubuntu last week. No problems. Now I've got the same problem on Linux Mint. The host responds to pings at <hostname>.local, but Remmina fails to resolve the address. Works OK with the IP address (not very useful since it's a DHCP address and changes). Only difference is that on Lubuntu I installed Remmina via a SNAP package; via a flatpak on Mint.